Paranormal Witch Book. Female lead is in hiding from assassins with her siblings
I am looking for a book I read a few years ago that had a strong female lead who was in hiding with her siblings from an assassin organization that modified and trained them.  I remember the witch practicing plant magic so maybe considered a hedge witch, green witch, or earth witch.
I think this series is a reverse harem.  I know that at the end of one of the books the female main character makes a pact with the land to work for the assassin organization to save her family. The next book is about the love interests saving her.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
